# Backup Unity's playerprefs with Android auto backup

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to specify what files should be backed up by Android's auto-backup that was added with API 23. I can add individual files (as [filename]) like this:

```
<include domain="file" path="[filename]"/>
```

However, the only way I've found to back up the playerprefs is to back up everything inside the "sharedpref" domain, like this:

```
<include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
```

Is there are a way to only back up playerprefs? I don't know if it's all in one file path, and what that path would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to output all the files in `/data/data/<appname>/shared_prefs` to work out what the name was. Turned out that the file is called:

```
<appname>.v2.playerprefs.xml
```

Where `<appname>` is the bundle identifier of the app (e.g. `com.example.myapp`). I'm not sure where the `v2` part is coming from, or if it varies between different setups. Seems like it's also what other people on the internet have found:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/accessing-playerprefs-from-android-native-java-plugin.367666/

Anyway, I added this line:

```
<include domain="sharedpref" path="<appname>.v2.playerprefs.xml"/>
```

and that backs up the unity playerprefs without backing up anything else that might be in the `shared_prefs` location.